# relation between $P(\mathbf{X}\geq t)$ and $P(\Phi(\mathbf{X}) \geq \Phi(t))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

The relation between $P(\mathbf{X}\geq t)$ and $P(\Phi(\mathbf{X}) \geq \Phi(t))$ for any non-decreasing non-negative function $\Phi$, non-negative $t$ and for positive random variables $\mathbf{X}$ is such that

$$
P(\Phi(\mathbf{X}) \geq \Phi(t)) \geq P(\mathbf{X}\geq t) 
$$

For functions like $\Phi(x) = x^2$, it can be easily imagine such an inequality as the 'size' of the sample space increases. For example if $x \in (0,2)$ then $x^2 \in (0,4)$. But what happens in case of other functions like $\Phi(x) = \sqrt{x}$ ?.  Here 'size' of the sample space decreases, if $x \in (0,4)$, then $\sqrt{x} \in (0,2)$ only. In such situation how one can show that above inequality holds ?

Comment: I learned probality theory long ago, so I may be wrong. But if $\mathbf{X}\geq t$ then
since $\Phi$ is non-decreasing, we have $\Phi(\mathbf{X})\geq \Phi(t)$ which implies the required inequality, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the size of the sample space," but since $\Phi$ is nondecreasing, $X\geq t$ implies $\Phi(X) \geq \Phi(t)$ by definition. (The converse doesn't hold; take $\Phi$ to be constant.)

Comment: @anomaly, by size i mean, for example in case of $x \in (0,2), t = 1$ and $g(x) = x^2$.  Intuitively, I can say that $P(X >= 1) \geq P(X^2 \geq 1)$ as $X$ can take values from $[2,4)$ with non-zero probability.  Regarding your comment, does the implication about $X \geq t$ and $\Phi(X) \geq \phi(t)$ holds even when we take probability ? If so, why ? Can you please explain it for $\Phi = \sqrt{} $ ?

Comment: I'm still unclear what you mean. $X = X(\omega)$ is a random variable. The set $\{X\geq t\} = \{\omega:\, X(\omega) \geq t\}$ is a subset of $\{\Phi(X) \geq \Phi(t)\} = \{\omega:\, \Phi(X(\omega)) \geq \Phi(t)\}$, from which the inequality immediately follows.

Comment: @anomaly. Ok. I got it. Thanks.